# QT SLOT called 1,2,3... times

Tags: c++, qt, qt-creator

I'm connecting a signal/slot but the slot is called multiple times (1, 2, 3...) every time I trigger the option, here are my classes:

mainwindow.h:

```
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();

private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
    Dialog *dialog;

signals:
    void s1(QString s);

private slots:
    void on_actionTooo_triggered();
};

#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

mainwindow.cpp:

```
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

void MainWindow::on_actionTooo_triggered()
{
    dialog = new Dialog(this);
    QString s = "hello";
    qDebug() << "CONNECT: " << connect(this, SIGNAL(s1(QString)),
            dialog, SLOT(s1(QString)), Qt::UniqueConnection);
    emit s1(s);
    dialog->show();
}
```

dialog.h:

```
class Dialog : public QDialog
{
    Q_OBJECT

public:
    explicit Dialog(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~Dialog();

public slots:
    void s1(QString str);

private:
    Ui::Dialog *ui;
};
```

dialog.cpp:

```
Dialog::Dialog(QWidget *parent) :
    QDialog(parent),
    ui(new Ui::Dialog)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

Dialog::~Dialog()
{
    delete ui;
}

void Dialog::s1(QString str)
{
    qDebug() << str << endl;
}
```

Every time the option is triggered in the main window, I connect the signal (just once), to the new dialog, but when I run, for example two times, it prints two "hello". If I put a `disconnect(this, 0, 0, 0);` before I connect the signals it works.

It seems odd to me that it maintains the connect even when the object is destroyed. It binds the connect to the same object created before. Is this the expected behavior?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are creating a new `Dialog` everytime you call `on_actionTooo_triggered()`. This `Dialog` isn't deleted at the end of your function. Therefore with the next call the signal `MainWindow::s1(QString)` is emitted to the two different `Dialog`s which results in multiple ouptuts in `qDebug`.

Answer (score 2):

```
void MainWindow::on_actionTooo_triggered()
{
    dialog = new Dialog(this);
    QString s = "hello";
    qDebug() << "CONNECT: " << connect(this, SIGNAL(s1(QString)),
            dialog, SLOT(s1(QString)), Qt::UniqueConnection);
    emit s1(s);
    dialog->show();
}
```

This code creates a new dialog each time it's triggered and sets up a connection between the newly created dialog and the MainWindow. While the connection is specified as "Unique", a new dialog is created each time, so the connection is not unique as the dialog instance is different.

Your code does not show that the dialog is being deleted and even if you close its window, the instance still remains in memory, so multiple objects are receiving the same signal.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Dialog` is never destroyed in this code. It's not even leaked as you pass `this` as a parent in the `Dialog`'s constructor, which makes the `MainWindow` responsible for this `Dialog` memory.

Thus you permanently create additional `Dialog` which slot will be triggered, and thus explaining why you see an incrementally increasing repetition of the output.